# VB.NET Multi-Threading INVOKE with multiple UI Objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, gdi+, invoke

Recently I was working on a project and everything was fine while debugging but after I create setup and installed the project I Got "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): GDI+..." error.
I figured out that the error probably caused by codes that like:

```
My.Resources.MyImage.Save(Application.Startuppath + "/Example.png")
```

or/and

```
Sub Example()
if My.Settings.PortBusy = False Then
dim t1 as new threading.thread(addressof IsPortOpen)
t1.start
My.Settings.PortBusy = True
End If
End Sub

.
.
.

 Function operaport() As Boolean
                Dim Client As TcpClient = Nothing
                Try
                    Client = New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9223)
                    Return True
                Catch ex As SocketException
                    Return False
                Finally
                    If Not Client Is Nothing Then
                        Client.Close()
                    End If
                End Try
    End Function



Sub IsPortOpen()
        Dim brvpt As Boolean = brvport()
        Dim gecpt As Boolean = geckoport()
        Dim cpt As Boolean = chromeport()
        Dim opt As Boolean = operaport()
        If brvpt = True Or gecpt = True Or cpt = True Or opt = True Then
            PortStatus.Checked = True
        Else
            PortStatus.Checked = False
        End If
        My.Settings.PortBusy = False
    End Sub
```

Instead these I Used

```
Dim copy As Image = My.Resources.MyImage
copy.Save(Application.Startuppath + "/Example.png")
```

and

```
PortStatus.InvokeSafe(New shit(AddressOf IsPortOpen))
```

But there is another "Threading.Thread" task and it interacts with multiple UI Objects. So how can I "InvokeSafe" multiple Objects in order to use multi-threading tasks that interacts with more than one Object?

Thank You so much For Reading :) .

Comment: Where is the *Invoke with multiple UI Objects* part? It's also not clear how that Image is involved, what uses it and what it's used for. Do mean you're trying to save the same Image to the same file from different threads?

Comment: This is terrible: `Application.Startuppath + "/Example.png"`. Your slash is the wrong way, don't use `+` to concatenate `Strings` (use the actual concatenation operator, i.e. `&`) and don't concatenate partial file and folder paths. That should be `IO.Path.Combine(Application.Startuppath, "Example.png")`.

Comment: The answer to this kind of question is to never interact with the UI controls from another thread. We have very good ways of running code on other threads without using threads explicitly. In your case, `Async`/`Await` seems like an ideal choice.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a mess but, if I'm getting the gist correctly, you just need to pass a delegate to `InvokeSafe` for a method that interacts with your multiple UI objects. I'm guessing that `InvokeSafe` is an extension method that tests the `InvokeRequired` property and calls the `Invoke` method of the control you call it on. I have to guess because you haven't bothered to explain. In that case, it doesn't matter what control you call it on. The point of those members is to ensure that you execute code on the thread that owns the specific control. That is going to be the same thread for every form and control, so it matters not which you control you use to get to that thread.